# Traced text on Illustrator CC rendering very strangely (creating outlines)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need to trace a text in my illustration, and for some very odd reason, all of a sudden, illustrator is rendering the traced text as shown below. I always use this tool and I never had any problems.

Text without tracing: 
[image]

Text after tracing (creating outlines):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got it! I had to chose "preview from CPU" under the "view" menu :)